# Jquery mouse over stops when I click menu item

Tags: ajax, jquery, mouseover, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a fixed-position accordion menu on the left. When I clicked a sub-menu item, main-page content changes but jquery mouse hover function is not working anymore. 
***( See Menu 1 -> Sub-Menu 1 | Sub-Menu 2 | Sub-Menu 3 )***.  
Here is page content loader javascript function :

```
var loadedobjects=""
var rootdomain="http://"+window.location.hostname

function ajaxpage(url, containerid){
var page_request = false
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
try {
page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
} 
catch (e){
try{
page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
}
catch (e){}
}
}
else
return false
page_request.onreadystatechange=function(){
loadpage(page_request, containerid)
}
page_request.open('GET', url, true)
page_request.send(null)
}

function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1))
document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText
}

function loadobjs(){
if (!document.getElementById)
return
for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
var file=arguments[i]
var fileref=""
if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file)==-1){ //Check to see if this object has not already been added to page before proceeding
if (file.indexOf(".js")!=-1){ //If object is a js file
fileref=document.createElement('script')
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
}
else if (file.indexOf(".css")!=-1){ //If object is a css file
fileref=document.createElement("link")
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
}
}
if (fileref!=""){
document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
loadedobjects+=file+" " //Remember this object as being already added to page
}
}
}
```

You can view sample of [**mouse over/hover boxes here.**](http://www.flynsarmy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/vert-scroll-boxes.html)

And here is my menu sample calling function ajaxpage.

```
<li><a id='im1'><img src="img/vmenu-insert.jpg" id="1" align='left'>Menu 1</a>
    <ul class='count'>
      <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('boxes.php', 'boxes');">Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('boxes2.php', 'boxes');">Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('box.html', 'boxes');">Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

If necessary here is php code sample just using a for loop to load more than one boxes.

```
<?php 
for ( $i = 0; $i<8; $i++ ) 
{
    echo "<div class='vertscrollbox'>";
        echo "<div class='slide imageslide'>";
            echo "<div class='slidewrapper'>";
                echo "<div class='image'>&nbsp;</div>";
                echo "<h3>menu1 sub2</h3>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='slide textslide'>";
            echo "<div class='slidewrapper'>";
                echo "<h3>menu1 sub2</h3>";
                echo "<p>";
                    echo "LOREM IPSUM";
                echo "</p>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

### [You can look at the full sample here.](http://cinarapart.net/demo/)

Comment: You're loading jQuery, but you're not using it for what it's really good at, ajax and event handlers !

Comment: You need to use delegation...